# Why does exporting vim as EDITOR in zsh disable keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: vim, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, environment-variables

My `.zshrc` looks like this:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
```

Now when I open a terminal and enter a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line, it doesn't work. Instead, the string `^A` (or some other string, depending on the shortcut I entered) gets entered to the terminal:

```
emlai:~ % ^A
```

Removing the word `export` from my `.zshrc` makes the keyboard shortcuts work properly:

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
```

Exporting `EDITOR` as something else than `vim` makes the keyboard shortcuts work too, e.g.:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/nano"
```

Why does this happen?

I tested this with `bash` as well, and the keyboard shortcuts work properly in all cases there.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`zsh` like most modern shells have a choice between two different keyboard mappings for command-line editing: a `vi` one and an `emacs` one. In some shells (like `tcsh` or `readline`-based ones like `bash`), the `emacs` one is the default and probably the one you expect.

With `zsh`, you get `emacs` mode by default unless `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` contains `vi` (if you're a `vi`/`nvi`/`vim`/`elvis` user (though also `vimacs` and if `$EDITOR` is `/home/victor/bin/emacs`...), `zsh` assumes you prefer the `vi` mode).

To force a particular mode regardless of the value of `$EDITOR`, add the tcsh-style:

```
bindkey -e # for emacs
bindkey -v # for vi
```

or the ksh-style:

```
set -o emacs
set -o vi
```

to your `~/.zshrc`. See

```
info -f zsh -n Keymaps
```

for details.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any reason to use `bindkey` over `set -o`?

Comment: @zenith, probably not. `bindkey` is the tcsh way and original way. Nowadays they should be equivalent.

Comment: fascinating! what if I want to set the `EDITOR` as nvim but not have the keymaps automatically exported?